# Ant design react TypeScript added from input required doesn't work

Tags: reactjs, antd, react-typescript

I tried to add  `react Typescript` project to [Antdeisgn forms](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-hkzvcx) input required it doesn't work.

**error here** 
when i added this      `const { getFieldDecorator } = this.props.form;`

i faced following error

> ```
>   TS2339: Property 'form' does not exist on type 'Readonly<Props> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }>'.
> ```

anyone know how to fix that correctly
**[stack blitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-qmqrky)**

**My code here**

```
    import React from 'react';
    import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
    import 'antd/dist/antd.css';
    import { Form, Input, Button, Checkbox } from 'antd';

    const formItemLayout = {
      labelCol: { span: 4 },
      wrapperCol: { span: 8 },
    };
    const formTailLayout = {
      labelCol: { span: 4 },
      wrapperCol: { span: 8, offset: 4 },
    };
  export  class DynamicRule extends React.Component<any> {


      check = () => {
        this.props.form.validateFields(err => {
          if (!err) {
            console.info('success');
          }
        });
      };



      render() {
        const { getFieldDecorator } = this.props.form;
        return (
          <div>
            <Form.Item  label="Name">
              {getFieldDecorator('username', {
                rules: [
                  {
                    required: true,
                    message: 'Please input your name',
                  },
                ],
              })(<Input placeholder="Please input your name" />)}
            </Form.Item>


            <Form.Item >
              <Button type="primary" onClick={this.check}>
                Check
              </Button>
            </Form.Item>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: Can you update your stack blitz here example with ReactDOM.render - so that we can have a finalized example.

Comment: `const { getFieldDecorator } = this.props.form;` how are you setting props in your example? this is your root component and it does not contain any props.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based of your comment below. I have taken your original code and added a constructor with a default value to the state:

```
// Added constructor and default value for checkNick
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      checkNick: false
    }
  }
```

and I also added handleChange because you had it in your code but it wasn't working:

```
  // Added handleChange
  handleChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({checkNick: e.target.checked})
  }
```

Here is the full working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-hkzvcx-bbuv6y

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import 'antd/dist/antd.css';
import './index.css';
import { Form, Input, Button, Checkbox } from 'antd';


class DynamicRule extends React.Component {

  // Added constructor and default value for checkNick
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      checkNick: false
    }
  }


  check = () => {
    this.props.form.validateFields(err => {
      if (!err) {
        console.info('success');
      }
    });
  };

  // Added handleChange
  handleChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({checkNick: e.target.checked})
  }

  render() {
    const { getFieldDecorator } = this.props.form;
    return (
      <div>
        <Form.Item  label="Name">
          {getFieldDecorator('username', {
            rules: [
              {
                required: true,
                message: 'Please input your name',
              },
            ],
          })(<Input placeholder="Please input your name" />)}
        </Form.Item>
        <Form.Item label="Nickname">
          {getFieldDecorator('nickname', {
            rules: [
              {
                required: this.state.checkNick,
                message: 'Please input your nickname',
              },
            ],
          })(<Input placeholder="Please input your nickname" />)}
        </Form.Item>
        <Form.Item >
          <Checkbox checked={this.state.checkNick} onChange={this.handleChange}>
            Nickname is required
          </Checkbox>
        </Form.Item>
        <Form.Item >
          <Button type="primary" onClick={this.check}>
            Check
          </Button>
        </Form.Item>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const WrappedDynamicRule = Form.create({ name: 'dynamic_rule' })(DynamicRule);
ReactDOM.render(<WrappedDynamicRule />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

Comment: Hi, i tried ,its not working ,  i upgrade to v3 to v4 but some components are not working, any solution for v3?

Comment: The examples are right there. Both for v3 and v4. I don't know what issues you are having. Looking at your original code I would assume that you did not build your react component correctly.
Share some code and I will see if I can identify your issue

Comment: Dear @core114, please do not change the online re-production source. or after working revert all changes. I read your codes for 15 min but after all I realized you changed somtthing.

Comment: @AmerllicA Hello, i tried to added this validation  for my project https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-hkzvcx

Comment: @SalminSkenderovic here is my conflict : when i added      `const { getFieldDecorator } = this.props.form;`  get this error   `TS2339: Property 'form' does not exist on type 'Readonly<Props> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }>'.`

Comment: @core114 I took your example from the comment and updated it to make it work. I see that you managed to wrap DynamicRule with Form.create so that you fixed the last error you got. Good job!

Answer (score 2):

For v3 of antd, pass in the `FormComponentProps` generic argument can resolve your problem.

```
import { FormComponentProps } from 'antd/lib/form'

export class DynamicRule extends React.Component<FormComponentProps> {
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

By looking at the code and dependency, I believe you are using Ant Design **version 4**. In Version 4, you can set rules in Form.Items like this:

```
 //Validators
  function handleTextValidation(rule:any,values:any,callback:any){
    console.log(values)
    const letters = /^[A-Za-z\s]+$/;
    if(!values.match(letters))
      callback("Please enter only letters");
    else
      callback()
  }

<Form.Item
name={['consignee', 'name']}
label="Consignee Name"
rules={[
  {
    required: true,
    message: 'This field is required!'
  },{ 
    message: 'The input should contain only letters',
    validator: handleTextValidation
  }
]}
hasFeedback={true}
  >
  <Input />
  </Form.Item>
```